# How to organize program's anchor code properly

Tags: anchor, rust

I have a program with around 10/15 methods, all in the same file which represents 2K lines of code +/-.

I would like to have one file with the method `pub fn my_method` and the struct `#[derive(Accounts)]` for this method , that would keep things more maintainable. Is that possible ?

If not, how to organize the code properly in order to avoid files with Ks of lines ?

Comment: This is a good answer to your question [https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4530/5712](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4530/5712)

Comment: thank you that's great !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to structure an anchor program?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/how-to-structure-an-anchor-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/coral-xyz/xnft/, this is the recommended way.

Putting the state in the `state` directory and instructions i.e. the functions together with the Accounts struct in the `instruction` directory.

But this opinion is subjective.

Comment: thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for !